# C macro parenthesis and asterisk in #define

Tags: c, memory, arm, embedded, driver

I have this line of C code from a real time clock (RTC) driver for a SoC chip from Nordic. I tried to look for what it does but it's a bit difficult to search. Can anyone please let me know what does it do? Especially the parentheses and asterisk.

```
#define NRF_RTC0                        ((NRF_RTC_Type            *) NRF_RTC0_BASE)
```

**NRF_RTC_Type** is a typedef of a struct and **NRF_RTC0_BASE** is #define'ed as 0x4000B000UL.

Thank you!

Comment: It's just a simple text replacement, it doesn't do anything special.

Comment: It's a typecast, casting `NRF_RTC0_BASE` to a pointer to `NRF_RTC_TYPE`

Comment: What do you mean by `NRF_RTC0_BASE is typedef'ed as 0x4000B000UL`? You can't typedef to a value, you can only typedef to a type.

Comment: If that's a mystery that's not a bad thing, but it sure is a sign you need a good [reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on how C works. We can't explain all of C in an answer here, you're going to need to do a lot of learning to understand what's going on. This isn't all that complex, but there's a lot of principles to absorb before any explanation we give could make any sense.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the answer. It makes sense.

Comment: @tadman. Thank you for sharing this. I'll definitely work on my C.

Comment: See this: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: @Lundin This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NRF_RTC0_BASE` identifies a set of hardware registers located starting at address `4000B000`. `NRF_RTC_Type` defines the mapping of the individual registers, and it probably adds the `volatile` qualifier to ensure that they are treated as I/O and not ordinary memory.

The parentheses make a typecast operation and the asterisk signifies a pointer type.

Use the macro `NRF_RTC0` to access the registers in a structured fashion.